# AlertDialog custom view with setView() inflated

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

The layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <EditText
        android:text="08:00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the code:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity()).apply {
        setTitle(R.string.settings)
        setView(R.layout.settings_dialog)
        setPositiveButton(R.string.save) { dialog, id ->

        }
        setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
    }.create()
```

and this is what it looks like:

[image]

The margin of the `LinearLayout` seems to have no effect. And the custom view seems to be inflated to the size of the screen, save for a margin that I think comes from the `AlertDialog` itself.

What is it that makes the custom view inflate this much? How to prevent it?

Comment: Not sure if your problem is the height or width of the dialog, the width has been mostly explained by the answer, but for the height, that's just how an empty view behaves in a linear layout. If you give it height = wrap content and the parent linear layout has the same, then the view takes all the height it can get.

Comment: Primarily with the height. I thought that "wrap_content" means: "take the least amount of space needed for the view". Is this not correct then?

Comment: Interesting: Making the 'View's height "0dp" fixed the height issue. I guess I don't get what "wrap_content" actually means.

Comment: You are pretty much correct as far as I know also, but the empty views just behave differently/strange, especially in linear layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this it looks ok:

```
LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <EditText
        android:text="08:00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Using `padding` instead of `margin` in the `LinearLayout`, and the `height` of the `View` set to `"0dp"` instead of `"wrap_content"`.

Answer (score 0):

You used weight on your View object and not on the other objects in this layout therefore
this code will give 'View' the maximum place it can take and will leave your edittext and textview no place.

You can either add weight to the text and edittext by
changing width to :

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

and adding this line:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

or you can remove the weight from the 'View' object.

Comment: The purpose of the 'View' is just to have the Text left aligned and the EditText right aligned. Why is there no margin from the LinearLayout to the edge of the AlertDialog?

Comment: What worked for me was adding "Space" object in the end:                                                                                                           <Space
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        />